# Angular Route issue

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

After creating the account, I want to retrieve the **ID** of the account created through a **route** but I receive the following error: **`NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'register-next'`**

The code

Register.ts

```
async postClient(){
    if(this.form.valid){
      const l = await this.load.create({
        message:'Enregistrement en cours...',
        spinner:'dots',
      })
      l.present();

      if(this.form.value.password === this.form.value.password_){
        this.clientService.registerClient(this.form.value).subscribe(res =>{
          if(res){
            l.dismiss();
            let id = res['id'];
            this.route.navigateByUrl('/register-next',id);
          }else{
            this.alertErreur();
          }
        });   
      }else{
        l.dismiss();
        this.alertErreurPassword();
      }  
    }else{
      this.alertErreur();
    }
  }
```

app.routing.ts

```
{
    path: 'register-next/:id',
    loadChildren: () => import('./pages/register-next/register-next.module').then( m => m.RegisterNextPageModule)
  },
```

Register-next.ts

```
this.id = this.router.snapshot.params['id'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let id = res['id'];
this.route.navigateByUrl(`/register-next/${id}`);
```